# How to save huge string to a txt in Python?

Tags: python, memory

Given a huge string (millions of tokens separated with a single space) how can I save it to a text file?
I tried and failed using:

> -np.savetxt with MemoryError *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   - fout.write() with MemoryError too

Is there a way in Python to deal with it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try that caused the quoted error message? Please show your code.

Comment: corpus = ... #in the format mentioned above
numpy.savetxt('corpus.txt', corpus)

Comment: So, `corpus` is a text string?

Comment: yes, a huge string containing millions of words separated with single spaces, like corpus = 'apple banana orange ... '

Comment: Did you try `open('corpus.txt','w').write(corpus)`?